# Something went wrong while creating your Kubernetes cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine Failed to request to CloudPlatform; Invalid request

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci

I was trying to configure a Kubernetes Cluster(nodes->3, machinetype->e2-standard-2), but every time I’m getting the same error.
" Something went wrong while creating your Kubernetes cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine
Failed to request to CloudPlatform; Invalid request"
I don’t see more information than the one above. I have a full admin account in my GCP account.
If someone can help me or point me out the mistake I will be grateful

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Refer this- https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/03/27/gitlab-ci-on-google-kubernetes-engine/ , in step 5, instead of creating kubernetes cluster , it is showing the error.